# Was photography school worth it?

Tags: learning, school

This question may not apply to most people on Photo.SE, but my question is directed towards those who have an undergraduate degree in photography or a closely related field:

- What experience as part of photography school do you feel you could not have acquired without having gone to school?
- Could you imagine an idea you were impressed upon in school that others who have not been to school for photography would have missed?
- Lastly, considering the ubiquity of photographic wisdom on the web, do you feel in hindsight formal school was a worthy investment?

Comment: What is the main thing you hope to get out of school? Do you have a degree in some other field already? For me, going to college and studying art allowed me to come into contact with people and ideas I might not have otherwise.

Comment: Yes; I studied mathematics and biology in undergrad.

Comment: Interested in what if any projects or experiences professional photographers reflected on as being influential in the academic career.

Comment: In that case, I would consider taking a course or two as a non-matriculated student.

Comment: Taking a course or two would be a way for you to figure out if it's right for you.

Comment: well, i would not disagree but i have had my fair share of credit hours.  i would prefer to be shared with the wisdom of those who have been there themselves.  portraiture interests me, well not portraiture but portraiture photographers.  i always hear portraiture photographers citing some sort of esoteric inspiration to their style. that intrigues me to learn about what they learned about in forming their own brand of photography.  for example.

Comment: You may want to also read this - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/64817/what-education-or-certifications-are-needed-to-get-work-as-an-image-processor-or/64840#64840

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at the pros and cons.

For example a BA in Photography:

Pros:

- Access to high end equipment and studio time
- Industry doors opened
- A chance to develop a "style"
- A chance to build a portfolio

Cons:

- A MASSIVE cost (Probably £10k PA + equipment, living costs etc)
- There are VERY few jobs that require this, and 1000+ people applying per opening
- Unlikely to ever pay for itself

Personally I know a lot of people who have a photography / artistic degree and now have completely unrelated jobs. Art / Photography have become "Lifestyle" degrees.
So to answer your question, based on overwhelming evidence based on friends who have done this:

In most cases: **No (certainly not financially)**